# How do I (temporarily) disable Navigation in my view when modal dialog exists?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

I have a standard UITableView with a UINavigation bar at the top with the standard back button, etc.

I have a button that pops up a "modal dialog" box, which is a view that sits on top of and almost obscures (but doesn't quite) the view underneath. Problem is, the buttons (including the "back" nav button) are still visible and thus touchable.

I've tried `setUserInteractionEnabled:NO` on the `view` of the UITableViewController, but that doesn't seem to work-- at least the navigation items are still touchable. But the navigationItem isn't a view subclass.

Any other ideas? Missing something obvious?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up with the same problem in a similar situation:
[iPhone: how do I set up a clear window-size "blocker view"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490574/iphone-how-do-i-set-up-a-clear-window-size-blocker-view)

Solved it using a transparent view that swallows events, sitting across the whole window. Feels kludgey but works.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
[[[tableViewController navigationItem] leftBarButton] setEnabled:NO];
```

Comment: Oddly, no. This `[[[self navigationItem] backBarButtonItem] setEnabled:NO];` appears to have no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar issue and used following to hide the nav bar:

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden: YES animated:YES];
```